# collecstatic does not push to files S3

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles, collectstatic

**EDIT:**

I have found that removing `import django_heroku` from my settings.py file allows me to push my static files to my AWS bucket. When I uncomment `import django_heroku`, `collectstatic` then pushes my files to the `staticfiles` folder.

`manage.py collectstatic` with `#import django_heroku`:

> You have requested to collect static files at the destination location as specified in your settings.

`maange.py collectstatic` with `import django_heroku`:

> You have requested to collect static files at the destination
>   location as specified in your settings:
>   /path/to/project/staticfiles

I don't know why this is or how to fix it. Now the question is: How can I run collectstatic for my django app on Heroku? Or do I need to run my heroku instance with nostatic? (e.g. `runserver --nostatic`)

**Problem:**

Whenever I run `python manage.py collectstatic` all my static files are placed into a **local** 'staticfiles' folder. I have set `STATICFILES_STORAGE = myapp.aws.utils.StaticRootS3Boto3Storage` however the files always go to 'myapp/staticfiles'.

**Settings.py:**

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_FILE_EXPIRE = 200
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myapp.aws.utils.MediaRootS3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myapp.aws.utils.StaticRootS3Boto3Storage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
S3DIRECT_REGION='us-east-1'

AWS_S3_URL = '//s3.amazonaws.com/%s' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

MEDIA_URL = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL

STATIC_URL = AWS_S3_URL + '/static/'
STATICFILES_LOCATION = STATIC_URL
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Expires': 'Thu, 31 Dec 2099 20:00:00 GMT',
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=94608000',
}
```

**myapp / aws / utils.py:**

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

StaticRootS3Boto3Storage = lambda: S3Boto3Storage(location='static')
MediaRootS3Boto3Storage  = lambda: S3Boto3Storage(location='media')
```

**Project Structure:**

```
myproject/
 |-- myapp/
 |    |-- aws/
 |    |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- utils.py
 |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |-- settings.py
 |    |-- urls.py
 |    +-- wsgi.py
 +-- manage.py
 |-- static/
 |   |-- scss
 |   |-- css
 |   |-- js
 |   |-- images
 |-- staticfiles/
 |    |-- **ALL STATIC FILES END UP HERE**
```

**Notes:**

- Changing `STATICFILES_STORAGE` seems to have no effect on the output
- `python manage.py collectstatic` results in:

  `You have requested to collect static files at the destination
  location as specified in your settings:`
  `/Users/nickmancini/Development/myapp/staticfiles`
- I do not get any error messages. All files are successfully created in the local staticfiles folder.
- Media files are successfully uploaded to my S3 bucket, but static files always go /Users/me/myproject/myapp/staticfiles
- According to the docs, after setting STATICFILES_STORAGES "all you have to do is run collectstatic and your static files would be pushed through your storage package up to S3"

**Questions:**

- What other information can I provide that would be helpful?

**Resources I've Consulted:**

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-from-a-cloud-service-or-cdn
- https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html
- https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/s3-static-media-files-for-django/

Comment: Have you tried STATIC_ROOT?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT   I have left STATIC_ROOT = '' before and it threw everything onto my C drive.

Comment: @dfundako I have tried setting STATIC_ROOT = ' '  & STATIC_ROOT =  AWS_S3_URL and neither had effect on the collectstatic. Should I set STATIC_ROOT to the AWS bucket (e.g. AWS_S3_URL)?

Comment: Set it to anything and see if that shoves all your static files to somewhere other than /Users/nickmancini/Development/myapp/staticfiles. If it does, that means you are on the right track I guess

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For anyone facing the same problem, the solution for me was: `django_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False)`

[which is also detailed at this github issue.](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/issues/25)